# How properly select data from DB according to filter in Eloquent?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have a filter.

Filter contains three fields. `Call_Date_From`, `Call_Date_Till`, `Telephone`.

So I need to select from `LEADS` (Lead Model) table all rows that fit filter.

In raw Php + MySQL I would write something like this:

```
$sql = ' WHERE ';
$post['call_date_from'] ? $sql .= ' `call_date` >= ' . $post['call_date_from'];
$post['call_date_till'] ? $sql .= ' AND `call_date` <= ' . $post['call_date_till'];
$post['telephone'] ? $sql .= ' AND `telephone` LIKE %' . $post['telephone'] . '%';

mysql: 'SELECT * FROM LEADS' . $sql;
```

So how properly do the same in Laravel Eloquent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you can do filter in Laravel Eloquent using [Query Scope](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#query-scopes).

In Model

```
class Lead extends Model
{
    public function scopeCallDateFrom($query, $date)
    {
        if ($date) {
            return $query->where("call_date", ">=", $date);
        } else{
          return $query;  
        } 
    }

    public function scopeCallDateTill($query, $date)
    {
        if ($date) {
            return $query->where("call_date", "<=", $date);
        } else{
          return $query;  
        } 
    }

    public function scopeTelephone($query, $telephone)
    {
        if ($telephone) {
            return $query->where("telephone", "LIKE", "%$telephone%");
        } else{
          return $query;  
        } 
    }
}
```

In Controller

```
public index() 
{
        $posts   = Lead::CallDateFrom(Input::get('call_date_from'))
                        ->CallDateTill(Input::get('call_date_till'))
                        ->Telephone(Input::get('telephone'))
                        ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
                        ->paginate();
}
```

Comment: Is not that too much "expensive" to request db several times?
In raw mysql we can do it by single query :(

Comment: It is not expensive. In each Query Scope, it is just building the final SQL statement not the db request. Only single query will be executed when you call the method ->paginate in this example.